# Error while setting LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

i am getting **error** when i am **using SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel** in my **java swing** code.
below is my code :: i don't know why am i getting error ?

```
try
{
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel());
}catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

it is showing me this type of error : 
[image]

Comment: Does `SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel` inherit from `LookAndFeel`? It looks as though it does not.

Comment: I think that rellated - [part General: -  point 1st.](http://www.javasoft.de/synthetica/faq/) (hint imports or saving this jar to libraries)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your issue is to specify the fully-qualified name of the LookAndFeel class as a string argument to `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` rather than try to pass an instance of it as an argument.

So, in your case, what you'd want to do is write:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("(package).(namespace).SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel");
```

...where you'd replace (package) and (namespace) by the correct values.

It may be this, but I'm not 100% sure as I don't use the theme you're referencing:

```
de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaStandardLookAndFeel
```

Comment: i am getting this type of error after above changes  ** java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaStandardLookAndFeel **

Comment: Is the theme's .jar file in your CLASSPATH?

Comment: Try adding the path to the .jar file to your CLASSPATH environment variable. Also, note that I said that I am not certain that the fully qualified name I gave in my answer is correct. You should verify it.

Comment: i have tried it but i don't how to include external jar to classpath variable.

Comment: What operating system? Windows, *nix, MacOS?

Comment: i am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) for setting LAF.
Try

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaBlackMoonLookAndFeel.class.getName());
```

to pass the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: @SarthakShah If any of the answers solved your problem please consider  accepting it or upvoting helpful ones.